# AWS custom region abbreviations in DBR report

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to extract the region name from DBR report generated by Amazon. The thing is that they use the prefixes I have not seen before:

CNN1 - china-north-1

USE1 - us-east-1

APC1 - asia-pacific-1

I have not seen such short abbreviations in their docs, and wonder, where can I see a list of all those abbreviations with their mapping to regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of region abbreviations can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/aws-usage-report-understand.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could not find that one with Google :/

Comment: Is there a  similar list for chinese regions?